# Moving commit to another branch, and fast forwarding original branch ahead

Tags: git, version-control, branch

What I have (assuming left is master, and the right is a feature branch):

```
   | * part of feature 2 (HEAD)
   | |
 B * |
   | * bug fix (unrelated to feature)
   | |
   | * part of feature 1
   |/
 A *
   |
```

So the obvious issue here, is that a bug fix (unrelated to the feature) got committed into a feature branch. Assuming this bug fix is critical, and needs to be applied to master before the feature branch gets merged back in, but the feature branch should also benefit from it.

So I believe I want to pick the commit out of the feature branch, apply it to master (in the right place), and then change the feature branches starting point to be after that commit.

What I *think* I want, in git topology:

```
          | * part of feature 2 (HEAD)
        B * |
          | * part of feature 1
          |/
 bug fix  *
          |
        A *
          |
```

How can I do this in terms of git on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would :

- cherry-pick bugfix in master branch
- do a rebase -i in the master branch to place the bugfix commit where you want it (between A and B)
- rebase feature branch onto the bugfix commit ("onto" is important and must be in the arguments, since you want only commits from A to be rebased on bugfix)

Every command is standard git, so with a little research you should be good

Comment: Or, if you aren't ready to rebase `feature` yet because of potential merge conflicts with `B` and later (in step 3 above, that is - you still want to do the first two), you can just `rebase -i` your feature branch and delete the bug fix - your feature branch will then still have the bug until you do rebase or merge with master, though.